# WPF TTF-font not applying

Tags: c#, wpf, truetype

I trying write app in WPF (C#) and I would like use ttf font for digital clock style.

I get font from internet, in archive i have 4 files. Add it to project into Font folder. Actions for file is Resource and Copy always. Then i add font-resource for my control in xaml:

```
<Control.Resources>
  <FontFamily x:Key="DS-Digital">.\..\Fonts\#DS-Digital</FontFamily>
</Control.Resources>
```

And use it to TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DS-Digital}"
  Foreground="GreenYellow"
  Text="{Binding GameTime, Converter={StaticResource SecondsCoverter}}"/>
```

It work. But it font not monospace. Then I downloaded another font. It monospace. In new archive i had only one file. Add it to project and use like previous font:

```
<Control.Resources>
  <FontFamily x:Key="DS-Digital">.\..\Fonts\#DS-Digital</FontFamily>
  <FontFamily x:Key="MonoDigital">.\..\Fonts\#Digital-7</FontFamily>
</Control.Resources>
```

and

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MonoDigital}"
   Foreground="GreenYellow"
   Text="{Binding GameTime, Converter={StaticResource SecondsCoverter}}"/>
```

But it not applied. What i doing wrong?

Thank you for answer and sorry my english.

Comment: Neither font is actually mono-spaced.  Perhaps you meant to use the [Digital 7 Mono font](https://fonts2u.com/digital-7-mono.font)

Comment: I download font from you link, and add it to project. It work, thanks!

Comment: It diffrent from my original file with Font name (if open it in Windows). My font is called "Digital-7" and font for you link is "Digital-7 Mono". 

Intresting, if I use
`code`<FontFamily x:Key="MonoDigital">.\..\Fonts\#Digital-7 Mono</FontFamily>`code`
it work with font from your link, and with my origin file. Obviously, problem in attribute font name in original file.